# geom_dotplot_interactive() removes stacking of points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

`geom_dotplot_interactive()` allows to create an interactive dotplot with the package `ggiraph`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
p <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_dotplot_interactive()
girafe(ggobj = p)
```

[image]

However, as soon as I try to add a tooltip, the points no longer stack.

```
p <- iris %>%
  mutate(rn = as.character(row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_dotplot_interactive(aes(tooltip = rn))
girafe(ggobj = p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltip introduces a new grouping(?), which makes it necessary to change some of the default arguments of `geom_dotplot_interactive` to get the same result. Namely, determine binpositions **across** groups and stack **across** groups:

```
p <- iris %>%
  mutate(rn = as.character(row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_dotplot_interactive(aes(tooltip = rn), binpositions = "all", stackgroups = TRUE)
girafe(ggobj = p)
```

[image]